# Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I knew the question is asked multiple times already,
but I still have no clue how to fix my code. Seem like I shouldn't call setState that way. But I took the example code from material-ui website and this should be straight forward ?

```
class Dashboard extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            activeStep: 0,
        }
        this.handleStep = this.handleStep.bind(this);
    }

    handleStep(step) {
        this.setState({activeStep: step});
    };

    render(){
        const { classes, match } = this.props;
        const sprints = ['sprint 1', 'sprint 2', 'sprint 3'];
        const { activeStep } = this.state;

        return (
            <div className= {classes.root}>
                <div className = {classes.container} > 
                    <Stepper nonLinear activeStep={activeStep} alternativeLabel>
                        {sprints.map((label,index)=>
                            {
                                return (
                                    <Step key={label}>
                                        <StepButton
                                            onClick= {this.handleStep(index)}
                                        >
                                            {label}
                                        </StepButton>
                                    </Step>   
                                )
                            })
                        }
                    </Stepper>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `onClick` of `StepButton` should be `onClick={() => this.handleStep(index)}`. Note the arrow function. This passes in a callback function that will run when `onClick` is triggered, whereas your code is calling `this.handleStep` during `render`. Otherwise, the way you are handling the state update is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

First,if you don't have the index parameter, the way you use bind is OK.Like this:

```
this.handleStep = this.handleStep.bind(this);
onClick= {this.handleStep}
```

Second,if you have parameter inside the onClick method, you will need the anonymous function to pass data.The anonymous function is ()=>.

So,with arrow function, you don't need to bind inside constructor.And there are many options：

```
//1
onClick={() => this.handleClick(index)}
//2
onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, index)}
```